# Listen to a JavaScript Callback in a Flutter Widget?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

Is there a way I can listen to a JavaScript callback in a Flutter widget?

I have this script in the `index.html` of my Flutter web app

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Paddle.Setup({
    eventCallback: function (eventData) {
      console.log(eventData);
    }
  });
</script>
```

How can I listen to this callback in my dart code of a Flutter widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a simple use case you can do it with JS event.

With a more complex use case, you will need to use a plugin.

For a simple use, in JS (index.html):

```
...
window.postMessage('{"myEvent": true}');
...
```

In dart, where you want to listen:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
...
listener(Event e) {
   print(e);
   print(jsonDecode((e as MessageEvent).data as String));
 }

 document.window?.addEventListener('message', listener);
...
```

And don't forget to remove your listener on dispose or other logic

```
document.window?.removeEventListener('message', listener);
```